# Assigning :hover to a class rather than an element

Tags: css

I'm working on a decent-sized project in which there are a bunch of elements I want to fade slightly when the user hovers on them. This is my current code:

```
.brand-images img,
.horList li a,
.producto__descripcion a,
.slider-btn,
.social-media__banner a,
.marca-productos__foto,
.marca-productos__nuevos-productos a,
.producto-zona__image a,
.campanas a {
    opacity: 1;
}

.brand-images img:hover,
.horList li a:hover,
.producto__descripcion a:hover,
.slider-btn:hover,
.social-media__banner a:hover,
.marca-productos__foto:hover,
.marca-productos__nuevos-productos a:hover,
.producto-zona__image a:hover,
.campanas a:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

This is obviously not very concise. My question is: is it possible to assign a `:hover`pseudo class to a normal CSS class? Something like this is what I had in mind:

```
.hover-fade { opacity: 1; }
.hover-fade:hover { opacity: .5 }
```

That way I'd be able to just apply that class to the elements I want. If it's not possible, any other suggestions of how to cut down the CSS are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Really? Instead of spending like 10 seconds checking it yourself, you went to SO, spend time writing a question?.. Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `:hover` to any valid css selector that has `:hover` pseudo element.

```css
div.wrapper a[name="link"]:hover,
a:hover,
a.a:hover,
[name="link"]:hover,
div a:hover,
.link,
.wrapper .link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><a name="link" class="a">Link</a>
</div>
```